# What is the equivalent of Rust's Vec<u8> in Java/Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, rust, java-native-interface

What is the equivalent type of Vec in rust to Java/kotlin?

`Vec<u8>` return [48, 130, 6, 55, 2, 1, 3, 48, 130, 5, 253, 6, 9, 42, 134, 72, 134, ...] in rust.

I tried using ByteArray in kotlin but as you can see few elements are out of byte range it gives out of bounds. Should we use IntArray? Or something else?

Comment: List, which is a variable data structure. But I don't think anyone would use List<Byte> to store byte data. You need to state what your purpose is.

Comment: "Not about programming"? What an absurd close reason...

Comment: It's the default close reason when people can't agree which community-specific reason to use. I'm not sure why it was closed myself, so am reopening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ByteArray in Kotlin is for signed bytes. If you want unsigned bytes (0-255), you can use the experimental [UByteArray](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-u-byte-array/)

```kotlin
val b = ubyteArrayOf(48u,130u,6u,200u)
```

or to return it from a function

```kotlin
fun getBytes(): UByteArray {
    return ubyteArrayOf(48u,130u,6u,200u)
}
```